# Access a property inside invokeMethod() implemented in a trait

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

The following Groovy trait implements the `GroovyInterceptable` interface to allow execution of code before and after method calls.

```
trait Bar implements GroovyInterceptable {
    def bar = "bar"

    @Override
    invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        System.out.println(bar)
        metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args).invoke(this, args)
    }

    def doSomething() {
    }
}
```

The following class implements the trait `Bar`.

```
class Foo implements Bar {
}
```

Have a look at the following code.

```
def foo = new Foo()
foo.doSomething()
```

The call to `doSomething()` is being intercepted by `invokeMethod()`. A `java.lang.StackOverflowError` occurs because accessing the property `bar` inside `invokeMethod()` implicitly makes a call to the getter of `bar` which in turn is intercepted by `invokeMethod()` just trying to access `bar` again.

*How can I access a class property inside `invokeMethod` without calling this property's getter or setter?*

In combination with the trait using `this.@bar` to access the property does not work.

The code `metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args).invoke(this, args)` to invoke the intercepted method could be incorrect although it works when using the trait logic directly inside a class.

**Edit for Solution:**

The accepted answer contributed by user [Opal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542270/opal) works like a charm in a script environment. Since the trait is part of a larger project and defined in its own file I made it work like this:

```
package com.example.project

trait Bar implements GroovyInterceptable {
    def bar = "bar"

    @Override
    invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        System.out.println(this.com_example_project_Bar__bar)
        metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args).invoke(this, args)
    }

    def doSomething() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `this.@bar`? With 2.4.0 it works correctly.

Comment: @Opal Thank you for the quick reply. Yeah, it works with `this.@bar`. I figured the example was not complete and my problem is slightly more complex so I edited the example code.

Comment: can I add it as an answer to be accepted?

Comment: @Opal If you can make it work in combination with the trait as shown in the example code, sure. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there's no need to use `@` for direct field access:

```
trait Bar implements GroovyInterceptable {
    def bar = "bar"

    @Override
    invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        System.out.println(Bar__bar)
        metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args).invoke(this, args)
    }

    def doSomething() {
    }
}

class Foo implements Bar {
}

def foo = new Foo()
foo.doSomething()
```

Comment: This looks correct by I get this exception: `MissingPropertyException: No such property: Bar__bar for class: de.appplant.workshop.data.Foo`

Comment: Strange. It rund ok on my machine.

Comment: Yeah, according to the [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_public_fields) it works. I am using Android Studio with Groovy 2.4.3.

Comment: The Code runs fine when executed as script. It fails with the exception mentioned above when the trait is declared in its own file. :-/

Comment: I can't reproduce it unfortunately because it's groovy on android.

Comment: I got it to work! I had to use `this.my_package_name_Bar__bar`.

Comment: Heh :D Congrats! How did you find it?

Comment: Honestly I just tried every combination possible of `this` or `Bar` with `@`,  `.` and `_` and hoped the code completion would give me some hint. :-D